# Difficulty with command line parameters

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

Welcome all,
I am required to prompt the user to enter "all, long, human or alh". I have developed some code however there is an error. I have used shellcheck.net to check whether the syntax of my code is appropriate.

the program itself should give a file and directory listing (based on the command line parameter received) and also show an error message if one of the options above is not selected.

- ”all” - do not hide entries starting with .
- “long” - use a long listing format
- “human” - use a long listing format and print sizes in human readable
  format
- “alh” – do all of the above

This is my code:

```
read -p "Please enter all, long, human or alh: " userInput

if [ -z "$userInput" ];
then
print f '%s/n' "Input is not all, long human or alh"
exit 1
else 
printf "You have entered %s " "$UserInput"
fi
```

the code itself works, however it does not show any directory listings based on the chosen parameter.

**Output:**

> Please enter all, long, human or alh: `all`
>   You have entered all

Comment: I think you need to run either `ls -l`, `ls -a`, .... `ls -alh`, depending on the given input. Your script has no `ls` command.

Comment: What if the user enters "foo"?

Comment: @choroba all it says is " you have entered foo "

Comment: @LarsFischer can you demonstrate that with a piece of code below please?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `case` command

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter all, long, human or alh: " userInput

case "$userInput" in
    (all) flags=a;;
    (long) flags=l;;
    (human) flags=lh;;
    (alh) flags=alh;;
    (*) printf '%s\n' "Input is not all, long human or alh"
        exit 1;;
esac

ls -$flags
```

Or, you can store the flags in an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter all, long, human or alh: " userInput

declare -A flags
flags=([all]=a
       [long]=l
       [human]=lh
       [alh]=alh
)

flag=${flags[$userInput]}
if [[ -z $flag ]] ; then
   printf '%s\n' "Input is not all, long human or alh"
   exit 1
fi

ls -$flag
```

Comment: Thank you very much @choroba, appreciate the efforts! will definitely try these out in a short while!